# How to install Python packages for version 3.6 on Mac

Tags: python, pip

Okay, so I have the following issue. I have a Mac, so the the default Python 2.7 is installed for the OS's use. However, I also have Python 3.6 installed, and I want to install a package using Pip that is only compatible with python version 3. How can I install a package with Python 3 and not 2?

Answer (score 1):

To download use

```
pip3 install package
```

and to run the file

```
python3 file.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you ask such a thing here?

https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html

> 4.3. Installing Additional Python Packages
>   There are several methods to install additional Python packages:
>
> Packages can be installed via the standard Python distutils mode (python setup.py install).
>   Many packages can also be installed via the setuptools extension or pip wrapper, see https://pip.pypa.io/.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-packages

> Installing Packages
>   pip supports installing from PyPI, version control, local projects, and directly from distribution files.
>
> The most common scenario is to install from PyPI using Requirement Specifiers
>
> `$ pip install SomePackage`           # latest version
>   `$ pip install SomePackage==1.0.4`     # specific version
>   `$ pip install 'SomePackage>=1.0.4'`     # minimum version
>   For more information and examples, see the pip install reference.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, before you run any command that you don't know what is it, please use `which your_cmd` or `whereis your_cmd` to find its path.